# The inflate method for my binding is not found (using Android, Data Binding.)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-databinding

I'm using data binding to bind the layouts in my Android app.

I have set up my layout ( my_custom.xml ) and the binding class is generated (MyCustomBinding), but Android Studio does not seem to find the .inflate(...) method of the Binding class right away, marking it as an error ( red text!).

The code seems to be correct though, since it compiles and builds just fine into an APK.

How do I get Android Studio to update correctly ?

## Code example:

This is my custom View code:

```
    public class MyCustomView extends FrameLayout {
    public MyCustomView(Context context) {
        this(context, null, 0);
    }
    public MyCustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }
    public MyCustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        MyCustomBinding binding = MyCustomBinding.inflate(inflater, this, true);
        binding.aButton.setText("Whatever");
    }
}
```

## layout is defined as:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <data>
    </data>
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/a_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Click me!"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:background="#000"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            />
    </FrameLayout>
</layout>
```

## And here's the issue: (highlighted red)

[image]

Comment: please post your code. Are u using Activity or Fragment?

Comment: Post "MyCutomBinding" class code.

Comment: This appears to me to be a bug in Android Studio 2.2. I've been using data binding without this issue for months until I upgraded today, and now I'm seeing it as well. There's a [bug report](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=222194) if you want to follow it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Something is not completing in Android Studio because you haven't actually implemented data binding.
Once you add a variable to your layout's `data` element, the `inflate` method will be found as you expect. That said, you're really not getting the benefit of databinding by setting the value of the text field directly through the binding. You should instead be setting a View Model in your binding, and then let the binding update the views accordingly. For example:

create a View Model:

```
public class MyViewModel {
    public final ObservableField<String> name;
    public MyViewModel(String name) {
        this.name = new ObservableField<>(name);
    }
}
```

and use it in your layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <data>
        <variable name="model" type="com.victoriaschocolates.conceirge.MyViewModel" />
    </data>
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{model.name}"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:background="#000"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            />
    </FrameLayout>
</layout>
```

(note the `variable` declared in the `data` element, and how it is referenced in the TextView's `text` attribute)

then bind the two in your custom view:

```
public class MyCustomView extends FrameLayout {

    public MyCustomView(Context context) {
        this(context, null, 0);
    }

    public MyCustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public MyCustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        MyCustomBinding binding = MyCustomBinding.inflate(inflater, this, true);
        MyViewModel model = new MyViewModel("Whatever");
        binding.setModel(model);
    }
}
```

Of course, it would probably be better still to have the data passed in through a setter in the custom view class, or even passed in from the container view (see http://developer.android.com/tools/data-binding/guide.html#includes)

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I realize that the intended way to use data binding is to use modes ad then bind values in xml. I find it somtimes easier though to just do the binding in code as opposed to creating a model object etc.

Comment: My solution for this is now to define an empty model class: public class EmptyModel {}, and then just define that as a variable [[  <variable name="model" type="com.myapp.EmptyModel" /></data> ]], without actually binding it to any views.

Answer (score 4):

You can try setting a custom class name to your Binding Layout, and referencing it in your custom view to make it clear which layout you using:

```
<layout>
    <data class="MyCustomBinding">
    </data>
</layout>
```

If this does not work, use `DataBindingUtil` instead of `MyCustomBinding`, which  returns the base DataBinding class and has a `inflate()` method:

```
MyCustomBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, this, true);
```

From the [docs](https://developer.android.com/tools/data-binding/guide.html#custom_conversions):

> Sometimes the binding cannot be known in advance. In such cases, the binding can be created using the DataBindingUtil class:

```
ViewDataBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater, layoutId,
parent, attachToParent);
ViewDataBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.bindTo(viewRoot, layoutId);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm not convinced that this answers my question in the best way though. I think this is NOT one of those cases where the MyCustomBinding is not known. I *do* import the class in Android Studio, and it does compile. The strange part it just that that .inflate() method is not recognized.

Comment: It does compile? Oh. My fault - but have you tried setting the class in the xml?

Comment: Yes it does compile. It's mostly an issue in Android Studio I believe. I have tried setting the class in the xml. While that allows me to change the classname of the binding, it does not fix the issue unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

this is updated answer based on latest databinding and androidx, i come here on this question to solve my own problem, after watching above answers i develop by own working code snippet. hope this helps

```
    public class CustomActionBar1 extends RelativeLayout {

    public MutableLiveData<String> title = new MutableLiveData<>("Sample text");
    CustomActionBar1Binding binding;

    public CustomActionBar1(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context, this);
    }

    public CustomActionBar1(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context, this);
    }

    public CustomActionBar1(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(context, this);
    }

    public CustomActionBar1(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        init(context, this);
    }

    private void init(Context context, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.custom_action_bar_1, viewGroup, true);
    }

    // helper to change title
    public void changeTitle(String title) {
        if (title != null)
            this.title.setValue(title);
    }

    public void setTitleVisibility(Boolean visibile){
        binding.titleText.setVisibility(visibile ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE);
    }

}
```

Xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="customActionBar1"
            type="com.actionBar.CustomActionBar1" />
    </data>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/yellow"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/action_bar_height"
        android:id="@+id/main_header_relative">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@{customActionBar1.title}"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/titleText"
        android:visibility="visible"
         android:textColor="@color/black" />


    </RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

Answer (score -1):

You dont need that type of stuffs, DataBinding includes DataBindingUtils class here we go.

```
public MyCustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle){
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    MyCustomBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, this, true);
    binding.aButton.setText("Whatever");
}
```