# Android Studio Data Binding Can't Resolve method inflate

Tags: android, android-studio, android-databinding

I've been having an issue with Android studio not resolving the inflate method for databinding classes. Everything compiles fine, I checked the build files and the method is there. I'm running 2.2 rc 2.

Method not resolving:

```
ResultsBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
```

Method in ResultsBinding:

```
public static ResultsBinding inflate(android.view.LayoutInflater inflater, android.view.ViewGroup root, boolean attachToRoot) {
    return inflate(inflater, root, attachToRoot, android.databinding.DataBindingUtil.getDefaultComponent());
}
```

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36552259/the-inflate-method-for-my-binding-is-not-found-using-android-data-binding

Comment: Yeah, that is what is happening. Thanks.

Comment: Cool! Glad it helps.

Comment: I don't think it is supposed to operate that way. I opened an issue and they are working on fixing it.
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=222243